# Hdri mix(light from one hdri, background from another)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, hdri

Can I use background from one hdri, but light source from another one?
For example, I have one hdri texture that conected to the world output. The only thing I need from this hdri is a light source. But I have another hdri that doesn't connect to world, and from this one I only need background image without any light sources. Can I somehow combine this HDRIs as I want?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the *Input > Light Path* node > *Is Cameray Ray* as factor in a *Mix Shader* between your 2 HDRIs

[image]

Comment: Yep, excectly what I need) Thanks!